# Primeng Context menu not working on tabpanel

Tags: html, angular, contextmenu, primeng

I have below code

```
<p-tabView #tabview *ngIf="mycondtion" class="page" [scrollable]="scrollable">
<ng-container *ngFor="let list of lists">
  <p-contextMenu [target]="link" [model]="items"> </p-contextMenu>
  <p-tabPanel [header]="list.listName" #link>
    <app-data-module [List]="list"></app-data-module>
  </p-tabPanel>
</ng-container>
```

on rightclick of tabpanel, it should show the context menu, but its not showing, i dont know what am i missing here? please help

Comment: does the p-contextMenu have to be inside the p-tabPanel that it references? also check the inspector - it may be showing in the DOM but not in the place you expect - it is position absolute and there is no position: rleative ancestor

Comment: @gavgrif yes you are right, in DOM its not in place we expect it to be,  is there a specific location to place p-contextMenu ? I thought context menu should be available for all tab headers , do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: sorry - no I have never used it - is there an appendTo that you can use to tie it to the element you need it to be on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use header template (instead of a "header="). Something like this:

```html
<p-tabView #tabview *ngIf="mycondtion" class="page" [scrollable]="scrollable">
  <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let list of lists">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <!-- Here is where all the header content will go, including the context menu -->
      <div #link>{{list.name}}</div>
      <p-contextMenu [target]="link" [model]="items"</p-contextMenu>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- Here is where the content of the tab will go -->
    <app-data-module [List]="list"></app-data-module>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

The main flaw here is, the context menu *only* appears when right-clicking on the <div>; clicking anywhere else in the tab header still won't work. I've not found a way around that, but hopefully this will help get you in the right direction.